# VM aborting with thread 1174 in Android

Tags: java, android, virtual-machine

This is log Trace

```
03-07 15:08:05.084: E/dalvikvm(1174): VM aborting  
03-07 15:08:05.093: A/libc(1174): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 1174 (com.company.gps)
```

My application was working fine with Emulator on API 16 but when I upgraded emulator device to API 17, I started to get this error but this error doesn't give any idea about the problem.

Can anybody tell me the problem here. I am making a GPS application which reads current co-ordinates of user and shows some near by places.

Comment: check the `Logcat` there should be content of call stack which will point to the place in code where problem appeared.

Comment: it means there is some problem with my code that's why this VM is aborting, so why the error is not displayed in red if there is any?

Comment: I'm not claiming that you have bug in code (it is possible). I'm just saying that you should show more of LogCat content especially part where call stack is shown, then we could have some starting point for further analysis.

Comment: I wasn't knowing that there could be some error in my code that could also lead to this behavior of VM,
thanks for giving me clue I have got the issue it was just the problem with setting image dynamically.

Comment: It might be multi threading issue (they can hide themselves and than come up mysteriously, like during change of platform). You really should show more LogCat entries now I'm playing role of fortuneteller.

Comment: Ya I will make sure next time the multi threading has no effect of app running. Ya fortuneteller :D

Comment: U got any solution bcoz I m facing same problem

Comment: It was issue in my code that was making problem, check your logcat thoroughly there might be issue in your code, as I was having in multi threading.